# React Native call the database on every page load

Tags: react-native, expo

I have 2 pages in my react native app. My application calls the database every time I route to the page, but after I add a new record to the database and go back to the previous page it only shows the previously loaded records, the new record only appears after the application is restarted. I tried useFocusEffect but it doesn't load the database at all. I'm using expo v49.

This is my index.js file

```
const router = useRouter();

const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState();
    const { getItem, setItem } = useAsyncStorage("@savedLogin");

    const readItemFromStorage = async () => {
        const item = await getItem();
        setValue(item);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        readItemFromStorage();
    }, []);

    return Platform.OS === "web" ? (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Text style={Styles.heading}>{i18n.t("expoIsNotSupportedAlert")}</Text>
        </View>
    ) : value === null ? (
        <StackNav.Navigator>
            <StackNav.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                name="Login"
                component={LoginScreen}
            />
            <StackNav.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                name="Register"
                component={RegisterScreen}
            />
        </StackNav.Navigator>
    ) : (
        <StackNav.Navigator>
            <StackNav.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
            />
            <StackNav.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                name="Add Meters"
                component={AddMeters}
            />
            <StackNav.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                name="Add Readings"
                component={AddReadings}
            />
            <StackNav.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
                name="Readings"
                component={ReadingScreen}
            />
        </StackNav.Navigator>
    );
}
```

This is my home page that calls the database

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
    const { getItem, setItem } = useAsyncStorage("@id");

    const readItemFromStorage = async () => {
        const item = await getItem();
        setValue(item);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        readItemFromStorage();
        console.log("Called");
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `SELECT * FROM meters where meters.userID="${value}";`,
                [],
                (_, { rows: { _array } }) => {
                    setMeters(_array);
                    console.log(_array);
                }
            );
        });
        console.log(value);
    }, [value]);
```

When I add record to database I call router.replace() function <Button onPress={() => {router.replace("/home")}}, from import {router} from "expo-router"

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Please share what database you are using.

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how can you do it .

```
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
const AllExpenseScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    getUpdateDataFromDataBase();
  }, [isFocused]);

  getUpdateDataFromDataBase = () => {
    // Apply your logic Here
  };
  return <View></View>;
};

export default AllExpenseScreen;
```

Comment: now it will load everytime even if there is no change?

Comment: if you want to get updated data from database then you have to you RTK Query . for more information i am adding another answer.